# Max Listener Error: How to close listeners in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting a Max listener error and I believe it’s coming from this part of my code. How do I close the listeners. Please see code below.

```
  initiateWorker(file, workTask) {
    const worker = new Worker(path.resolve(file));
    worker.on('message', (result) => {
        if (result.success) {
            workTask.done(null, JSON.parse(result.response));
        } else {
            workTask.done(result.error, null);
        }
        this.removeWorker(worker);
    });
    worker.on('error', (err) => {
        workTask.done(err, null);
        this.removeWorker(worker);
    });
    worker.on('exit', () => {
        workTask.done(null, null);
        this.removeWorker(worker);
    });
    return worker;
}

removeWorker(worker) {
    this.workers.splice(this.workers.indexOf(worker), 1);
    worker.terminate();
}
```

I have tried modifying the code, adding removeListner. But I might be doing it incorrectly.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is any problem in the posted code. I assume you are talking about `MaxListenersExceededWarning`; this is raised when you put many listeners on the same emitter, the warning limit being 10 by default. Your code shows 3 listeners on `worker` at initialisation (i.e. limited to one time).

Comment: Yes. I am getting MaxListenersExceededWarning. This is the only place in my code where I am using .on.  Could other parts of the code be calling Worker and adding more and more listeners? If so how do I ensure they close?

Comment: Try this: immediately after `new Worker` line, put `worker.setMaxListeners(3)`; then run with `node --trace-warnings your_code.js`. This should tell you where the fourth listener is getting bound. (Or, it will tell you it has nothing to do with `worker`, and pinpoint which emitter is the problem.)